# Paypal not returning token or payerid (php), using api calls

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Bizarre issue with testing Paypal payment API (using PHP):

Paypal sends back the necessary token and payer ID "get" variables that allow it to continue on to the actual Paypal Test Store page just fine when I run my test from a localhost version of my website (in this test I use the actual domain's url for the return url).

When I upload these exact same code files to my website, I never get to the Paypal Test Store page at all. Through all kinds of debugging (echoing and exiting at various points in my paypalprocess.php file), I've narrowed it down to the fact that when I run from the website, Paypal does not return either the get token or the get PayerID. (Which it does just fine when I run from localhost.

Here is the config file:

```
$PayPalMode  = 'sandbox'; 
$PayPalApiUsername  = 'busmysandboxtest.gmail.com'; 
$PayPalApiPassword  = 'xxxxxxxxx'; //Paypal API password
$PayPalApiSignature     = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
$PayPalCurrencyCode     = 'USD'; 
$PayPalReturnURL    = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/paypalprocess.php';
$PayPalCancelURL    = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/paypalcancelreg.php';
```

The paypalprocess file seems pretty large to include here -- I've used the same code before with another website and it worked fine both in the sandbox and live modes, running from the website and not localhost.

I hope somebody has some ideas -- I've uploaded my paypalprocess and config files obsessively to make sure that what's on the webhost is the same as what's on my PC, and I can't see why the process works when originating from a folder on my PC and doesn't work when originating from my website's folders. (I know that I'm getting to the paypalprocess.php file file initially and also the config file initially in both places just as I should be.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure if this will help, but I found another stackoverflow question that provided a link to the following: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php--net-3271

Check out the comments - there's something on there that says to switch over from sandbox to Paypal

Which brings to this link: http://www.spicelogic.com/docs/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-for-Website-Payments-Standard/Managing-PayPal-SandBox-accounts-80

I don't know all your code, so I can't check them myself - but you could go over it to see if any of it is similar to what you have, and what you can do about it